# GROUP BY and display once in same value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display once in multiple rows with same value

My Query like this

```
SELECT name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(class) class, 
       COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM report 
GROUP BY name
```

and the data like this

```
+----+----------+-------+
| ID | NAME     | CLASS | 
+----+----------+-------+
|  1 | John     |  10   | 
|  2 | James    |  21   | 
|  3 | James    |  21   | 
|  4 | John     |  10   | 
|  5 | Augie    |  22   | 
|  6 | Augie    |  22   | 
|  7 | John     |  10   | 
+----+----------+-------+
```

I wanna make output like this, name will display once

```
Name : John, class : 10, Total : 3
Name : James, class : 21, Total : 2
Name : Augie, class : 22, Total : 2
```

Comment: what is the question, your query seems fine expect you're querying for score and your data shows "class" instead. also it seems to be missing AS.

Comment: Where does score come into it , score isn't in the data?

Comment: @yasoh AS is optional, and frequently omitted

Comment: @P.Salmon oh I mean that is class not score, sorry

Comment: @Beadyyy, do you need this result in single column

Comment: So, what's wrong with the query in the question?

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
SELECT name,Class,COUNT(*) AS total FROM report GROUP BY name,Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation and group by :

```
select name, class, count(id) as total
from tablename
group by name, class
```